# Convergence of sequence of discrete measures on $\mathbb{T}$ in total variation norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R/Z}$ be the circle. Prove that the space of discrete measures on $\mathbb{T}$ is closed under convergence in total-variation norm in the set of measures on $\mathbb{T}$.

I thought doing it in the following way:
Suppose we denote $\mu_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_n(k)\delta_{x_{n,k}}$, for the sequence to be convergent can we require $\forall k\in\mathbb N, \exists\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n(k)=c(k)$? Also, can we require existence of a set of points $K\subset \mathbb{T}$ s.t. $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge n_0 \forall y\in K,\mu_n(y)\neq 0$? thus taking $$\mu=\sum_{y_k\in K}c(k)\delta_{y_k}$$ we get $$\Vert \mu_n-\mu\Vert=\sum(c_n(k)-c(k))\to 0.$$

Is that sufficient? Can one fix this solution or a give a simpler one?

Comment: You're trying to show that if each $\mu_n$ is discrete and $\lim_n\|\mu_n-\mu\|=0$ then $\mu$ is also discrete. **Hints:** (1) Total variation convergence means that $\lim_n\sup_B|\mu_n(B)-\mu(B)|=0$ (the supremum being taken over Borel subsets of $\Bbb T$), (2) Because $\mu_n$ is discrete, there is a countable set $C_n\subset\Bbb T$ with $\mu_n(\Bbb T\setminus C_n)=0$, (3) How much mas can $\mu$ give to the complement of the countable set $C:=\cup_n C_n$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks. why the definition with the $\lim\sup$ is correct? How can I show that $\mu(\mathbb{T}\setminus \bigcup_n C_n)= 0$? Is that correct?

Comment: (1) Check out the definition of total variation convergence; it amounts to uniform setwise convergence (whence the $\sup$). (2) Take $B=\Bbb T\setminus\cup_nC_n$. Then $B\subset \Bbb T\setminus C_n$ so $\mu_n(B)\le\mu_n(\Bbb T\setminus C_n)=0$ for each $n$. Finally, $\mu(B)=\lim_n\mu_n(B)$.